# Searching for ampersands in a MySQL text field

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT 'events' AS tbl,events.*, users.name, users.lastname,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events_participants WHERE 
        events_participants.eventid=events.id) AS participants 
       FROM 
       (events INNER JOIN users ON users.id=events.organizer) 
       WHERE events.isConfirmed<=1 
       AND events.category='art&culture' 
       AND events.city='Roma(Rm)'AND events.datetime >= '2011/02/22 22:30' 
       AND events.datetime<='2011/06/22 23:00' ORDER BY events.datetime DESC
```

The ampersand: `&` in `art&culture` causes the query to not return rows.

Comment: what programming language are you using to push this query to mysql.

Comment: What error do you get? What doesn't work?

Comment: That's valid SQL as the `&` needs no special escaping. I would therefore assume the query simply didn't return anything. Either because the entry doesn't exist, or the DB contents have been encoded. Please use a DB browser to verify. If you use PHP and one of the sadly widespread "sanitization" functions it might be `&amp;`

Comment: Are you sure that the value is actually an ampersand (&) and not the html entity for an ampersand (&amp;)

Answer (score 0):

If that's the full query, looks like there should be a space between '2011/06/22 23:00' and ORDER BY

Answer (score 0):

Possible issues:

- `datetime` is a reserved word. Try replacing `events.datetime` with `` events.`datetime` `` everywhere it appears.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can search for Ampersands in a text field like this:

```
mysql> create table yar (id INT, mytext TEXT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into yar values(1, 'art&culture');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from yar;
+------+-------------+
| id   | mytext      |
+------+-------------+
|    1 | art&culture |
+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from yar where mytext = 'art&culture';
+------+-------------+
| id   | mytext      |
+------+-------------+
|    1 | art&culture |
+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```